# Swagger UI not updated when deploying to AKS

Tags: spring-boot, azure-devops, swagger, azure-aks

I have a Spring Boot application that exposes multiple APIs and uses swagger for documentation. This service is then deployed to AKS using Helm through Azure DevOps.

When running locally, the swagger documentation looks updated but however, when I deploy it; the documentation goes back to the outdated version. I'm not really sure what is happening during deployment and I am unable to find any help on the forums.

As far as I know; I do not think there is any sort of caching taking place but again I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you suspect an incorrect version of your application is running in the cluster following a build and deployment.

Assuming things like local browser caching have been eliminated from the equation, review the state of deployments and/or pods in your cluster using CLI tools.

Run `kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name>`, the pod template will be displayed which defines which image tag the pods should use. This should correlate with the tag your AzDO pipeline is publishing.

List the pods and describe them to see if the expected image tag is what is running in the cluster after a deployment. If not, check the pods for failures - when describing the pod, pay attention to the `lastState` object if it exists. Use `kubectl logs <podname>` to troubleshoot in the application layer.

It can take a few minutes for the new pods to become available depending on configuration.